# User sessions and two CakePHP applications running in the same machine

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2, cakephp-2.3

I have **2 CakePHP applications** running on the same machine. 
Both of them need a previous registration to have access to them and the first thing users see is the login form.

I have realized that when I do login in one of them, then, I can access to the other web application without being asked for my credentials to login. (which is not correct)

In my Controllers of both applications I have this to deny access without a previous login.

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Auth->deny();
}
```

But this seems not to work properly when I use the same browser and I do login in one of this applications.

Why is this happening? Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cookiename and/or cache prefix should be different for both applications.

You can find those settings in the `core.php` file

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying to separate Auth sessions of my two applications (same DB, same core) for days. Session config was fine, but cache prefix is what fixed the mess when working with both apps at the same time. I was getting wrong Login/Logout redirects, missing controller actions, etc.