# issue in CakePHP authentication

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I am using two cakephp framework . Problem is when I logged in to 1 st one, without login I can login to 2nd one by using same session. 
how to resolve this issue .   I am using cakephp 2x

Comment: It is difficult to help you without properly laying out your problem. This does not tell me anything specific

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User sessions and two CakePHP applications running in the same machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627712/user-sessions-and-two-cakephp-applications-running-in-the-same-machine)

Answer (score 0):

From what you are saying I understood that you have two applications running on the same server (the default realm for Auth plugin). And what is happening is that once you login in one application the other lets you access the protected locations without the need to login (I've faced this).

IF this is your issue you can either change the prefixes of the applications in the configuration file `app/Config/core.php`.
It is one line like this:

```
<?php  [...]
    $prefix = 'myapp_';
```

Change the prefix to other name.

OR

Configure the `realm` key in the AuthComponent configuration to other value than the 'servername' which is the default. 
For this one check the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) and search for 'realm'.